# Assigning shortcut to PyQGIS script in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, gui, shortcuts

Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to a (custom or not...) script of the **Processing Toolbox** in QGIS?

I have not found any information about it so far.

Comment: You can assign shortcut keys to plugins which is described here: [How to call a method by a key shortcut](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/snippets.html#how-to-call-a-method-by-a-key-shortcut). Perhaps this can be modified to work within a script?

Comment: Thx Joseph ... i'm gonna check this !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an example of how to open the Processing "Join attributes" algorithm by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (you can copy and paste it into the QGIS Python console):

## For QGIS v3.x

```
# Function to open the "Join attributes" algorithm's UI
def openAlgorithm():
    processing.execAlgorithmDialog("native:joinattributestable")

# Assign "Ctrl + Shift + 1" to openAlgorithm()
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QKeySequence
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QShortcut
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ControlModifier + Qt.ShiftModifier + Qt.Key_1), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut.activated.connect(openAlgorithm)
```

That's it! If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> the Join Attributes UI will open:

[image]

---

Note 1.1: Get a readable list of algorithm ids and names in this way:

```
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print("{}:{} --> {}".format(alg.provider().name(), alg.name(), alg.displayName()))
```

Note 1.2: See [Qt5 docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qt.html#Key-enum) for a comprehensive list of keys.

## For QGIS v2.x

```
# Function to open the "Join attributes" algorithm's UI
# See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156633/how-to-launch-processing-tool-user-interface-using-pyqgis
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from processing.gui.CommanderWindow import CommanderWindow
cw = CommanderWindow(iface.mainWindow(), iface.mapCanvas())
def openAlgorithm():
    alg = Processing.getAlgorithm("qgis:joinattributestable")
    if alg is not None:
        cw.runAlgorithm(alg)

# Assign "Ctrl+Shift+1" to openAlgorithm()
from PyQt4.QtWidgets import QShortcut
from PyQt4.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ControlModifier + Qt.ShiftModifier + Qt.Key_1), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut.activated.connect(openAlgorithm)
```

That's it! If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> the Join Attributes UI will open:

[image]

Note 2.1: *You can get the names of the available algorithms by entering these lines in the QGIS Python console:*

```
import processing
processing.alglist()
```

Note 2.2: *See [Qt4 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#Key-enum) for a comprehensive list of keys.*

Note 2.3: *You can call `shortcut.activated.disconnect(openAlgorithm)` to finish the association between the shortcut and your algorithm's UI.*

Comment: It does for sure ...

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I see in Qt documentation QShortcut under QtWidgets and not QtGui (both Qt4 and Qt5). In my case for QGIS3 and PyQt5 I had to do: from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QShortcut

Comment: It's now fixed Miro!

Comment: How do I need to change this in Qgis v3.x to load my own project model instead of a native process? Can anyone help?