# Using Shortcut for QGIS Processing Script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, shortcuts

I grabbed code from [Assign shortcut to a script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168562) to assign shortcuts for quickly changing to preset scales. 
When I did it for one shortcut, it was working - but then, when applying several ones it didn't anymore - though the script runs without any errros..
Clues, anyone?

```
# https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168562/assign-shortcut-to-a-script/168739
#====================================
##[User scripts]=group
#====================================
from PyQt4.QtGui import QShortcut, QKeySequence
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from processing.gui.CommanderWindow import CommanderWindow

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

def chgScale2500():
    canvas.zoomScale( 2500 )

def chgScale5000():
    canvas.zoomScale( 5000 )

def chgScale10000():
    canvas.zoomScale( 10000 )


#Assign "Ctrl+1", "Ctrl+2", .. to chgScaleX
shortcut1 = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ControlModifier + Qt.Key_1), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut1.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut1.activated.connect(chgScale2500)

shortcut2 = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ControlModifier + Qt.Key_2), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut2.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut2.activated.connect(chgScale5000)

shortcut3 = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ControlModifier + Qt.Key_3), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut3.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut3.activated.connect(chgScale10000)

# for resetting shortcuts
#shortcut1.activated.disconnect(chgScale2500)
#shortcut2.activated.disconnect(chgScale5000)
#shortcut3.activated.disconnect(chgScale10000)
```

Comment: Interesting, your script works fine for me when I pasted your code into the **Python Console**. How did you run the script?

Comment: Thanks for trying! I did it via the "Processing Toolbox" -> "Create new script"..

Comment: 2.12 Lyon.. Saved correctly.. But I'll try a restart and report!

Comment: Darn, it was just something in the cache, after trying several version of the script! A restart of QGIS solved the prob! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joseph, would you please put your comment as an answer, so I can check it?

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working! I tend to restart QGIS quite often as my scripts fail all the time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running scripts, a good idea is to unload all the *modules* that were imported and remove any *dependencies*. This seemed to be what was causing your scripts to not work the way they should.

Probably the easiest method to achieve the above is to simply **restart QGIS**.